# Faster way to manipulate mutli byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this:

```
var data = new byte[100,100,1];

//data is populated from external source

for (var h = 0; h < 100 ; h++)
{
    for (var w = 0; w < 100; w++)
    {
        if (Data[h, w, 0] > 10)
        {
            Data[h, w, 0] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

and I am just saying if the value is above 10 then change it to 255.

But, it is quite slow.

Is there a quicker way to do the above?

Comment: Changing to [Paraller.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) might speed up.

Comment: removing nested loop can also improve your performance

Comment: @HamzaHaider I'm not sure there is any other way, they'll still need to check all 10k positions to check if it's over 10.

Comment: @Reniuz trying to implement as I type thanks :)

Comment: I think that code is about as efficient as you can get. If you want to update 10,000 individual variables, it's going to take a while. The way to improve it is to question why you have 10,000 identical variables that need identical changes. Perhaps you could simplify the data structure, or maybe only one or two values will be read, so you could leave the change until then, or some other work-around.

Comment: @HamzaHaider Will see if it makes a difference. thanks

Comment: @RobinBennett Thanks for that viewpoint,  that structure is what I am given by an external source so have limited control :(

Comment: What do you mean "quite slow"? How are you timing this? What are your expectations? PS: as the code stands you're using both `data` and `Data` - I'm assuming they should be identical.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen slow for my needs.  Anyway I can improve the efficiency of my code is a good thing don't u think?

Comment: How are you measuring?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I am using a fps counter

Comment: If you could flatten the data into a single zero-indexed single rank array and use spans of that for the ranks of what is currently a multi-dimensional array that would also help. An array of arrays would be faster for some things (because they're szarrays internally) but slower for some others (because there's more indirection) especially with locals reducing the amount of indirection.

Comment: @JonHanna Thanks I will give this one ago after trying the pointer answer

Comment: They can be done in combination with the other answers, but they also make for complications that affect other uses of the arrays, so might not be worth it.

Comment: @JonHanna yes, i was being drawn to that conclusion. But like the idea and maybe useful elsewhere. thanks again for the usggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also mix this with `unsafe` and *Pointers*. However, you need to jump through a couple of more hoops. It should give you a bit performance in release mode with pointers

```
// p is because you cant used fixed in a lambda
public static unsafe byte* p;

// AggressiveInlining to compile in line if possible
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static unsafe void DoOp(int i)
{
   if (*(p + i) > 10) *(p + i) = 255;
}

public static unsafe void Main()
{
   int x = 10, y = 10, z = 1;  
   var data = new byte[x, y, z];

   fixed (byte* pbytes = data)
   {
      p = pbytes;
      Parallel.For(0, x * y,
         new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount},
         DoOp);
   }
}
```

Comment: My god! i just accepted the other answer. i shall test this now and get back to you

Comment: @AndrewSimpson make sure you test in release mode, let us know how it goes

Comment: that's a very good point, The amount of time I forget to do this and then when I release my code I am presently surprised when it works more efficiently :)  need coffee 1st!

Comment: I get the error the 'i' does not exist here:  if (*(p + i) > 10)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson sorry i had the `if` in the wrong spot

Comment: that's cool. gave a better result. I am going to try the other suggestion of flattening an array so I can be objective

Comment: @AndrewSimpson what the "fps" difference between this and the other solution?

Comment: @Joelty the 'fps' difference is that 1 is using pointer and the other is not

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Oh I thought that by "fps" you meant the way of measure the performance of given algorithm in compare to normal nested arr + if (in main post)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson just changed to static, which will give you slightly less allocations and another tiny boost

Comment: my raspberry pi crashed so having to rebuild before testing with static

Answer (score 3):

You can perform parallel operation for outer `for loop` so as to increase performance.

```
 var Data = new byte[100,100,1];
 //data is populated from external source

 // Parallelize the outer loop for h 
 Parallel.For(0, 100, h=>
 {
    for (var w = 0; w < 100; w++)
    {
        if (Data[h, w, 0] > 10)
        {
            Data[h, w, 0] = 255;
        }
    }
 });
```

Note: you must include `using System.Threading.Tasks;` in your source code.

Comment: Thanks I will test this. i will also test removing the nested array and get back

Comment: @AndrewSimpson without the nested loop not all values >10 will be changed, you'll miss 9800 records.

Comment: @Matt thanks. i was looking to see if that meant having 2 seperate loops

Comment: Just a note. If you perform only one small if statement (fairly small operation) on 100x100 matrix, paralleling tasks might add more overhead and performance will decrease.

Comment: Thanks, improved my fps 'around that code segment' by 4-5fps. Excellent!

Comment: I have been given a different answer which I will test out. pls do not get offended if i switch my accepted answer.